# Importance of Combinatorics

Tags: mathematical-economics, statistics

I would like to know how important combinatorics is. I am an undergraduate student looking to take more math courses and I saw and intro to combinatorics as an option. The reason I am asking is because the course seems cool to me but preference is usually given to compsci majors thus there are hurdles when enrolling which is why I was wondering what application of combinatorics are there in economics?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "important". Important for what? Grades on your undergrad econ courses? Grad school application? Potential uses in future jobs?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I will edit and clarify my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: @HerrK. Most matching theory is combinatorics. And network economics makes heavy use of graph theory. Much of social choice theory is essentially combinatorial.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: It didn't occur to me that problems in those fields are combinatorial. But now that you said it, I see why they are. I stand corrected.